# TOSHIBA L 50 B graphics card drivers for linux Debian 9

Tags: linux, laptop, drivers, debian, graphics-card

I have notebook Toshiba L 50 B and I installed linux Debian 9, but I have problem with double graphic card. The amd card is without driver then useless, and the whole graphic performance is very low also with simple videogame (as SuperTuxKart that is a previous generation). I tried to search on amd website for installing driver but there are only support for other distributions; I installed them and my computer crashes at boot every time (but now I disinstalled drivers and can boot).

Also my computer is very slow at any thing especially loading windows, probabily I think it is a problem of XWINDOW that uses graphic acceleration: anything uses it and then slow down all overall.

Please help me and suggest the correct drivers for the intel card and amd card; open source both proprietary are good!

```
utente@JJjjo:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems HD Graphics 5500
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Broadwell-U Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev cb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
09:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Radeon R7 M260
utente@JJjjo:~$
```

Comment: Such 'dual' graphics configuration is called hybrid graphics. Debian Wiki has a section about it here: https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo.

Comment: This answer (of Larssend) reply about the amd card. But i have problem with both intel card and amd card. It's impossible that a recent card goes slow with tuxkart! Help me with intel card